# Switching stylesheet URLs in Polymer.dart

Tags: css, dart, dart-polymer

I have a custom element that I'd like to be themeable. The `link` element that I put in my template, though, appears to be replaced by Polymer with a `style` element containing the contents of the URL (even in Dartium), which means I can neither bind the `href` attribute (which I hear doesn't work anyway) nor change it programatically on an event.

Actually, even without being able to switch it, I'd like to be able to set it once when the element is created, so I can create different instances of the element with different themes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide more information what you wan't to accomplish (beside switching the CSS file). see http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html#theming-an-element . You can apply styles programmatically or use `^`, `^^` (or the new `/shadow/` `/deep-shadow/` not yet supported in Dartium) for theming.

Comment: I don't want to accomplish anything besides switching the CSS file. Unfortunately, the shadow DOM-piercing selectors aren't really ready for use yet, and the article you linked to refers to Polymer.js, not Polymer.dart. (There are differences, including that the style property is read-only in Dart.) But see my answer for how I got it working.

Comment: What do you mean by `the style property is read-only`. You can change both the CSS rules or the style properties (not the style property itself of course) in PolymerDart programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that you can programatically specify a stylesheet if you add a style element with a CSS import:

```
factory MyView(String themeUrl) {
    MyView view = new Element.tag('my-view');
    view.shadowRoot.append(new StyleElement()
        ..id = 'theme'
        ..appendText("@import url('$themeUrl');"));
    return view;
}
```

I was able to switch it like this:

```
void switchTheme(String themeUrl) {
    StyleElement theme = shadowRoot.getElementById('theme');
    theme.replaceWith(new StyleElement()
        ..id = 'theme'
        ..appendText("@import url('$themeUrl');"));
}
```